# zsh: print literal text from the command line

Tags: shell-script, zsh

I want to print some literal text, including things like `;` and `#`.

In `bash`, I can use [(credit)](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/aliases.html):

```bash
echo_literally_helper() {
  local str; str=$(history 1)
   # Remove leading space number space
   echo "$str" | sed -En 's/^ *[0-9]+ +[[:graph:]]+[[:blank:]]//p'
}
alias echo-literally='echo_literally_helper #'
```

Then:

```
$ echo-literally a; b; c
a; b; c
```

How would I do the same in `zsh`?

Comment: If zsh fails to offer a way to do this, I consider it an excellent reason to use zsh

Comment: The main difficulty here is that `history` does not list the currently running command line in `zsh`. Putting a `#` into an alias, so that the remaining line is not evaluated is actually possible (if the option `INTERACTIVE_COMMENTS` is set).

Comment: See also [Prevent terminal from displaying previously executed command](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/105544)

Comment: History substitution makes this fail, eg:  `echo_literally !$`
Somehow we'd need to save and restore `$-`, and `set +H` inside the alias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be possible by using [`$history`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fparameter-Module) and [`INTERACTIVE_COMMENTS`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-INTERACTIVECOMMENTS):

```
echo_literally_helper () {
  local str="$history[$(print -P %h)]"
  echo "${str#*echo_literally\ }"
}
alias echo_literally='echo_literally_helper #'

# for using `$history`. (does not needed in zsh-5.5.1 here, though.)
zmodload zsh/parameter

# zsh does not enable this option by default, so turn on.
setopt interactivecomments
```

Then:

```
% echo_literally a; b; c
a; b; c
```

Note: it uses `print -P %h` and `$history` to get the current history command rather than `history` (or `fc`) bulitin command.

---

Here are some references for zsh documentations.

> `history`
>   This associative array maps history event numbers to the full history lines.
>   ...
>
> -- [zshmodules(1): zsh/history, zsh modules](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fparameter-Module)

--

> `INTERACTIVE_COMMENTS` (`-k`)  
>   Allow comments even in interactive shells.
>
> -- [zshoptions(1): Input/Output, Options](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-INTERACTIVECOMMENTS)

--

> Comments:
>   In non-interactive shells, or in interactive shells with the `INTERACTIVE_COMMENTS` option set, a word beginning with the third character of the histchars parameter (‘#’ by default) causes that word and all the following characters up to a newline to be ignored.
>
> -- [zshmisc(1): Comments, Shell Grammar](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#index-INTERACTIVE_005fCOMMENTS_002c-use-of)

--

> `%h`
>   `%!` 
>    Current history event number.
>
> -- [zshmisc(1): Shell state, Simple Prompt Escapes, Prompt Expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Shell-state)

Comment: This works under `zsh -f` but not with my standard config. Before I start bisecting, do you have any hints?

Comment: No. I have no idea. Could you provide your config?

Comment: It was `setopt posix_aliases`. Editing now.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know this! So, posix claims about valid “Alias Name”. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_10

Comment: See also `$history[${(%):-%h]` to avoid the command substitution.